# Reactive version of quarkus-keycloak-admin-client extension?

Tags: quarkus

Is there a reactive version of the quarkus-keycloak-admin-client extension?

When I add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
2021-11-21 18:27:51,546 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CapabilityAggregationStep#aggregateCapabilities threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please make sure there is only one provider of the following capabilities:
capability io.quarkus.rest.client is provided by:
  - io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive::jar:2.5.0.Final
  - io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client::jar:2.5.0.Final
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CapabilityAggregationStep.aggregateCapabilities(CapabilityAggregationStep.java:147)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:887)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:330)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:93)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:450)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:149)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:105)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have that yet. You can track [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/20505) issue for updates on when that will change.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error is saying that we have to choose one of the [providers](https://quarkus.io/guides/capabilities):

> Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CapabilityAggregationStep#aggregateCapabilities threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Please make sure there is only one provider of the following capabilities**:
> capability io.quarkus.rest.client is provided by:
>
> - io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive::jar:2.5.0.Final
> - io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client::jar:2.5.0.Final

So, go to your pom.xml file and make sure to have one of them (`quarkus-rest-client` or `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`).

I believe you have to remove the `quarkus-rest-client` dependency and use only the `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`.